# How to use Spring IOC with Swing

Tags: java, spring, swing, spring-mvc

I am developing a desktop application using Swing, but with this I want to use Spring framework to use IOC, and that I want to do using Interface technique. But I am getting nullPointerException when I call a function by instance of an Interface and that interface is implemented by a class in which called function is declared.

Here is my simple app code:

### Interface:

```
public interface IEmpMasterService {    
    public InternalResultsResponse<EmpMaster> maintainEmpMaster(
            EmpMaster empMaster);
}
```

### Implementer class:

```
public class EmpMasterService implements IEmpMasterService {    
    private IEmpMasterDAO empMasterDAO; 
    public IEmpMasterDAO getEmpMasterDAO() {
        return empMasterDAO;
    }
    public void setEmpMasterDAO(IEmpMasterDAO empMasterDAO) {
        this.empMasterDAO = empMasterDAO;
    }
    @Override
    public InternalResultsResponse<EmpMaster> maintainEmpMaster(
            EmpMaster empMaster) {
        InternalResultsResponse<EmpMaster> response = new InternalResultsResponse<EmpMaster>();
        //some logic her...
        response = getEmpMasterDAO().maintainEmpMaster(request);
        return response;
    }}
```

### DAO Interface:

```
public interface IEmpMasterDAO {
    InternalResultsResponse<EmpMaster> maintainEmpMaster(
            EmpMasterRequest request);
}
class Implementing DAO:
public class EmpMasterDAO extends HibernateDaoSupport implements IEmpMasterDAO{
    @Override
    public InternalResultsResponse<EmpMaster> maintainEmpMaster(
            EmpMasterRequest empMasterRequest) {
//hibernate code goes here...       
        return resultsResponse;
    }
}
```

### Main Class:

```
public class EmpManager extends javax.swing.JFrame {    
    private IEmpMasterService empMasterService;
    private static ApplicationContext context;  
    public IEmpMasterService getEmpMasterService() {
        return empMasterService;
    }
    public void setEmpMasterService(IEmpMasterService empMasterService) {
        this.empMasterService = empMasterService;
    }
public static void main(String args[]) {
        context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"ApplicationContext.xml"});
empMasterService = (EmpMasterService)context.getBean("empMasterService");
}
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        String name = jTextField1.getText();
        String salary = jTextField2.getText();
        EmpMaster empMaster = new EmpMaster();
        empMaster.setEmpName(name);
        empMaster.setSalary(Double.parseDouble(salary));  
//***** getting Error at this line *****//    
        InternalResultsResponse<EmpMaster> response = getEmpMasterService().maintainEmpMaster(empMaster);       
    }
```

my ApplicationContext.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
           http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">
    <import resource="dataSource.xml"/>
       <bean id="mainFrame" class="org.UI.EmpManager">
        <property name="title"> <value>Spring Example</value></property>    
        <property name="empMasterService" ref="empMasterServiceImpl"></property>    
    </bean>     
    <bean id="empMasterServiceImpl" class="org.service.EmpMasterService">
        <property name="empMasterDAO" ref="empMasterDAOTarget"></property>      
    </bean> 
    <bean id="empMasterDAOTarget" class="org.DAO.EmpMasterDAO">
        <property name="hibernateTemplate" ref="matrixHibernateTemplate"/>
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

And when i click on button an error that i am getting.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.UI.EmpManager.jButton1ActionPerformed(EmpManager.java:140)
    at org.UI.EmpManager.access$0(EmpManager.java:132)
    at org.UI.EmpManager$1.actionPerformed(EmpManager.java:67)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Just a thought - since your context seems to be initialising correctly, are you sure you don't have two different `ApplicationContext.xml` files hanging around in different directories?

Comment: *"its very urgent"*  Your time schedule is not our concern.  Perhaps you need a consultant instead.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for your great support...

Comment: @maksimov thanks for reply, I looked in my app directory but there is only one ApplicationContext file.

Comment: @Balasaheb Spring is typically printing out errors/warning if there're any problems with the initialisation - watch out carefully when you debug through this line: `new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(new String[]{"ApplicationContext.xml"});`

Comment: `but with this I want to use Spring framework to use IOC` It's not really IOC if you plan to pull dependencies from your context.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How are you creating EmpManager, there is a bean in your application xml for the manager, but it also contains your main method.  Then within your main method you're getting the application context, and setting the service bean, so your EmpManager bean is not doing anything in your application context.

I'd recommend extracting the main method into a different class in which you load the Application Context and use getBean only on the UI manager. The way you currently have it set up ignores a lot of the IoC capabilities of Spring by directly grabbing beans from the Application Context, rather than letting Spring do that for you.

This might not solve your problem directly, but it will at least allow Spring to have a single point of entry, and keep DI in the hands of Spring, rather than relying on you to set them yourself.

Comment: thanks, now I know what going wrong with this code, actually i am creating a button and adding an actionListener to it, so that time i am creating new ActionListener that's why it giving an error. Now I have created classMyActionListener which implementing ActionListener and  in that class i have used this bean.

Answer (score 0):

Something is missing in your code.

Your main function you've posted does not invoke creation of any Swing frame. Is it really the code you are calling?

Second, there are mismatch in the bean names, in your xml the bean is named `empMasterServiceImpl`, and in code you're taking the `empMasterService`. It will not work.

Comment: thanks for reply, actually empMasterService is an instance of IEmpMasterService Interface and that implemented by EmpMasterService. I created a bean of interface and mapped it to implemented class. And this technique i have used in my web project and that is working good. I think here is another problem that i have missed something to add.